# Custom ListenTCP processor works fine on 1.11.4 but fails to deploy on version 1.11.4.2.0.4.0-80

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

I created a Custom ListenTCP processor by creating new socket handlers and referring them in CustomListen TCP. I was able to deploy it on my mac and tested it with a sample file that has a different incoming delimiter and works great on my mac.(version 11.4)
However, My org is using this version: Cloudera Cloudera Flow Management (CFM) 2.0.4.0  1.11.4.2.0.4.0-80, Tagged nifi-1.11.4-RC1
So, I tried to change the version appropriately on my mac for deploying the nar file into our Cloudera cluster but it is failing with ClientAuth class not found in SSLContextService( version  1.11.4.2.0.4.0-80)

Here is the link for 1.11.4 on my mac works fine
[image]

Modified to 1.11.4.2.0.4.0-80 and fails with not finding $ClientAuth

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/7fe8858d22f580ad9dcd96ebafb59dbe5e73f5cb/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-ssl-context-service-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/ssl/SSLContextService.java#L41)
it was deprecated and somehow not found in your CFM jar.
Maybe putting this enum in your custom code solves your problem .

```
 enum ClientAuth {
    WANT,
    REQUIRED,
    NONE
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! We obtained the right code from Cloudera 
that is relevant to our environment but again ran into a similar issue
of not finding another class (RestrictedSSLContext).
We did similar to what you suggested above ,creating that missing class locally in our project and then it worked !
Thank you for taking time to answer this.